# My screen renders blotches and corrupted text. Moves with the windows they're in

Tags: windows-10, display

Sometime during the last couple of days, my computer quit rendering content on the screen properly. It affects all applications, but is most noticeable in Windows Terminal and Chrome. It appears to simply be parts not being drawn.

- Missing bottom of colon in `wt`: [image]
- "adduser", "ci", "completion" and "deprecate" all have pieces missing in their text[image]
- "script" and the final ")" are missing pieces [image]
- An example from SO. "where" is missing a piece [image]
- An example while writing this question (note the "t"s): [image]
- An example after posting the bounty (note the "7" and "100"): [image]
- Finally, this one looks like a bird: [image]

I have been unable to find the common denominator. I *appears* to only affect text, but that could simply be where it's most noticeable. It also moves in response to changes on the screen. It's very noticeable in `wt` since every time the cursor blinks, the defect moves. These paragraphs are also tripping out as I'm writing this, but change with every character I type. Highlighting the defective text also causes it to be fixed. An oddity though is that the defects "survive" scrolling. I can scroll `wt`, and the defect scrolls with the text, and also survives minimizing. They do not however survive if they are scrolled off the screen. The above images were all taken with the built-in "Snip and Sketch" tool, so obviously the defects also survive having a screenshot taken of them. It also shows up on the lock screen!

This seemed like a graphics driver issue, so I redownloaded and installed my graphics drivers and ensured they were fully updated. I also made sure my laptop has all available Windows updates except for W11.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? It's driving me crazy.

---

- **PC**: Nitro AN515-45
- **OS**: Microsoft Windows 10 Home (10.0.19044 Build 19044)
- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics, 3201 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)
- **GPU**: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU (Driver version 511.79)

---

## Additions:

- I was told to try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, but unfortunately that didn't help. There was a defect on the screen that survived it. And of course it got a lot better when they were looking at the screen, and has since gotten worse.
- I tried toggling ClearType since this seems connected to text. It had no effect though.
- I actually got a Nvidia driver update just now (released Marth 14th?), but unfortunately, it did not help.
- I have also run Windows' Memory Diagnostic Tool with the default settings. It didn't find anything.
- The problem also survived updating to Windows 11 unfortunately.
- I ran `chkdsk`, it found some issues, but even after fixing them, the problem remains.
- I ran MemTest86's 13x4 test, and it didn't find any memory errors. I've since read though that you should really do 8 tests to do a complete scan, so I'll probably do that overnight.
- I ran `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and `sfc /scannow`. Neither reported any issues. I also tried running them in Safe Mode since I read that's preferable.

---

Here is a (cropped) full screen screenshot that shows the issue in `wt`:

[image]

The defects change on every letter entered.

This is weird though. The top is "█", the bottom is "#". Note how the defects only affect "#":

[image]

---

I wasn't sure if this was related, but I've had different games crashing for the same reason (attempting to dereference small pointer values), and just now my machine hard shutdown while playing XCOM 2. When I checked the event viewer, this was the primary error:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000000a (0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff8076561d37d). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 38bb5032-2731-4988-a3b2-cad295eae4fc.
```

For some reason, my machine keeps attempting to do out of bounds reads and writes to memory. Normally I'd chalk this up to the programs being faulty, but there's a lot of weird memory-related issues that all seemed to have appeared at the same time.

Comment: When the problem occurs, take a screenshot of the whole screen by pressing PrtScn, then paste the screenshot to another program that allows images. Check if the imperfections are still there. If still there - this is a software problem. If they are gone - your screen is dying.

Comment: @harrymc That's why I included the screenshots above. Those were taken with a print screen function. Yes, it appears to have nothing to do with the screen thankfully. It also follows windows as you move them which I wouldn't expect from a dying screen.

Comment: @harrymc As requested though, I uploaded a full-screen sample taken using PrtScn (cropped after the fact).

Comment: INTERESTINGLY though, I thought if I pasted "█" into the terminal like I did "@" (it's light in the terminal), I could see the defects better. It doesn't happen with that symbol as the background though! It only seems to affect plain ASCII-encoded characters?

Comment: Try to use another font?

Comment: @harrymc I tried replacing the terminal font family with most of the families in the first table [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) and it presented with all of them.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Neither indicated any problems. The former returned "The restore operation completed successfully.", and the latter returned "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.". Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: So your [answer that you have now deleted](https://superuser.com/a/1712460/167207) is no longer valid? I mean you deleted it, but just asking.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: It came back.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I fear that the next step is [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as doing a Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate In case a repair install does not resolve the issue _(select to keep all files/settings)_, it could then only be a driver issue or third-party software since doing so completely rules out the OS itself.

Comment: @harrymc It survived a complete reinstall of the OS. The glitches even appeared on the initial Windows setup screen.

Comment: @JW0914 The drivers and third party software should have been wiped by a reinstall correct? It still persists. This is starting to look like a hardware issue.

Comment: Is this localized to the Radeon Graphics adapter or the GeForce? If it happens so early, it must be the Radeon, so see if you can disable it. Deleting it within Device Management should do it until the next reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Disabling the Radeon graphics device did actually seem to fix it! I updated it though using AMD's Adrenalin. I'll see if I can play around with removing and installing drivers. Thank you for your assistance narrowing the problem down.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment the problem seems to be localized to the
Radeon Graphics adapter, as disabling it has stopped the problem.

I find it hard to believe that it can be a software problem, as this
Radeon driver is used on too many computers to have such a flagrant bug.

If keeping the Radeon disabled in effect solves the problem,
this looks like a hardware problem. As the Radeon is soldered-in
and cannot be replaced (except by a specialist),
the only feasible solution is that of keeping it disabled.

For a laptop, this might shorten your battery life when not on mains power.

Comment: Keeping it disabled seems like the only fix. I've tried reinstalling the driver several times now, and I'm consistently seeing that as soon as it's enabled, the graphics go wonky. If I have warrrenty for a repair shop (Memory Express), do you think this is sufficient grounds to request a replacement of the CPU?

Comment: If you have warranty, this is a very serious defect. We can't know if the repair will be a replacement of the CPU or the motherboard, so don't be too specific in your demands.

Comment: Excellent, I really appreciate it. I will be back in a while with hopefully good news.

Comment: So, they took it and will get it back to me in "roughly 5 business days". They agreed though that from the description, a problem with the Radeon chip sounded like a possibility, and will do whatever repair is required; up to replacing the laptop. I will post an answer when the final verdict comes back, but since they've taken over diagnostics from here, I'll award the bounty to this answer for narrowing the problem down to a testable cause. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

They're replacing the motherboard.

Unfortunately, it won't be in until Monday, and then will likely take until Tuesday to complete the repair unless I'm lucky. I will update this post when I know the complete details of their report.